# Materialize CSS - Conflicts with versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm with a problem here, using the Materialize CSS and two versions of jQuery. 
I'm making a site onepage, and I put the smooth scrolling effect(I get in this site - http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links ) and it uses a version different of jQuery 3.1.1 (what the Materialize uses). So, when I leave the jQuery 3.1.1 active in code, the effects of JS from Materialize works, but when I leave the jQuery 2.1.1(used by smooth scrolling) activated, the smooth scrolling does not works. I tried to use the method "no conficts" of jQuery, but does not works too.

Comment: don't use two versions of jQuery on the same page! If smooth scroll works with 2.1.1, and you're using jQuery 3.1.1, then smooth scroll should still work. There is an easy way to use two versions of jQuery on the same page, but just don't do it, no decent developer will advise you to do this.

Comment: Materialize and jQuery both use the `$` prefix.  Instead of using `$.noConflict();`, try assigning jQuery to a new variable as a prefix -- `var jq = $.noConflict(); jq(document).ready(function(){});`.

Comment: @Adam I'm using two jQuery in the same page because I've a problem with versions

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'll try it